# Android is there any way to get gridview data inside of current pageview?

Tags: android, android-gridview, baseadapter, android-pageradapter

I have a Calendar Application which have multi views level: DayView, MonthView, YearView.

In class CalendarPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter:

```
    Context mContext;
    Calendar initDate; // init date is displayed on page 100, by default init date is current date
    int viewLevel;  // 0: century view, 1 decade view, 2: year view, 3: month view, 4: day view
    int totalPage;
    CalendarBaseAdapter gridAdapter;

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View view = generateView(position);
        container.addView(view);
        return view;
    }
public View generateView(int position){
    Calendar viewData = getData(position);
    if(viewLevel != 4) {
        GridView gridView = new GridView(mContext);
        gridView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        /** Some code here */

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                initDate = gridAdapter.getData(position);
                if(mContext instanceof LunarCalendar){
                    ((LunarCalendar)mContext).changeViewLevel(1);
                }
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Init date " + initDate.getTime().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.i("INFO", "Init Date " + initDate.getTime().toString());
            }
        });
        Log.i("INFO", "GridView was generated for " + viewData.getTime().toString());
        return gridView;
    } else{ // lunar day view
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.lunar_day_view, null, false);

        /** Some code here */

        return layout;
    }
```

The problem is: when I access yearView for 2016/07/25 will display 12 months of this year and log as below:

```
07-25 16:11:35.016 I/INFO: GridView was generated for Mon Jul 25 16:11:01 GMT+07:00 2016
07-25 16:11:35.018 I/INFO: GridView was generated for Sat Jul 25 16:11:01 GMT+07:00 2015
07-25 16:11:35.020 I/INFO: GridView was generated for Tue Jul 25 16:11:01 GMT+07:00 2017
```

And when I click month "Jul" my gridview display data for "2017/07/25" but my expected data is "2016/07/25"(see log below)

```
07-25 17:27:46.096 I/INFO: Init Date Tue Jul 25 16:11:01 GMT+07:00 2017
07-25 17:27:46.099 I/INFO: GridView was generated for Tue Jul 25 16:11:01 GMT+07:00 2017
07-25 17:27:46.102 I/INFO: GridView was generated for Sun Jun 25 16:11:01 GMT+07:00 2017
07-25 17:27:46.106 I/INFO: GridView was generated for Fri Aug 25 16:11:01 GMT+07:00 2017
```

How can I get current gridView data?